# I saw he had used one of the patterns his textbook submitted

Tags: tense

Here is the task from my textbook:

Add the preposition or adverb

*George said – Friday he was leaving __ Britain __ an invitation __ the British Council. He showed me their letter __ invitation and his answer __ it. **I saw he had used one __ the patterns his textbook submitted __ acceptance**.*

I am not sure about the last sentence. Why is the verb submit in the past tense. This sentence expresses – but maybe I am wrong – that he used one of the pattern that his textbook recommends for the acceptance. So I would use the present. Is the past tense used because of the tense shift. Is the correct version: *I saw he had used one of the patterns his textbook submitted for acceptance*.

Comment: How can a textbook submit something? Are you missing a gap indicator?

Comment: I also think this question assumes  cultural knowledge.  Who does the accepting, the British Council? or George?

Comment: Are you sure _submitted_ isn't _suggested_? You seem to have left out or mistyped portions of the question. Are there prepositions and adverbs from which you are expected to choose? Without more and better context, it is difficult to help you. Please use the **[edit]** link to add the _entire question_ and context, and be certain that you have copied it accurately. What is the title of your textbook?

Comment: There is really "submitted" there. The verb "submitted" is suspicious to me as well… In fact , I am not interested in the preposotions but just in the used tense.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the *tense* of **submitted**. Are you expecting past perfect there? Because of "I saw he **had used**..."

Comment: I expected the present tense. Like in the sentence: he told me that one and one is two.

Comment: I saw he {had taken} one of the umbrellas the school {leaves, left, had left} in the foyer for unexpected downpours. Any one of those verbs would work in the right set of circumstance, present, past, past perfect.  I saw he had used one of the patterns his textbook {suggests, suggested, had suggested} as appropriate.

Comment: If you're referring to the textbook as an extant resource that one could consult right now if one wanted to do so, the present.  If you're referring to a textbook chapter George was consulting at the time, simple past. If you're referring to a textbook chapter that had been the subject of a lecture earlier in the semester, past perfect.  The temporal circumstances are wide open here, and there's nothing to constrain your choice, absent further context.